# Django smart select doesn't work with Django CSP

Tags: python, django, content-security-policy, django-smart-selects

I admit that I am truly a beginner in this area.
I made a database driven website with django.

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

# Create your models here.
class Company(models.Model):
     ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
     soc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
     class Meta:
        ordering = ('soc_name',)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.soc_name

class Plant(models.Model):
     ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     company_id = models.ForeignKey(company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Interventions(models.Model):
     ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     start_date = models.DateField()
     description = models.TextField()
     company_id = models.ForeignKey(company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     plant_id = ChainedForeignKey(
         Installations,
         chained_field="Company_ID",
         chained_model_field="Company_ID",
         show_all=False,
         auto_choose=True,
         sort=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return str(f"{self.start_date}, {self.plant_ID}")
```

I used Django-Smart-Selects so that in Interventions Form, when a Company is selected, the Combo Box of the Plants (which belong to the respective Companies) is automatically filtered.
Here an image to make it easier to understand:
[image]

Up to here everything works perfectly.
So I tried adding Content Security Policies (CSP) to my site.
To do this, I added these lines of code to the **Settings.py** file:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
     [...]
     'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',
]

CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'none'",)
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'unsafe-inline'", "https:")
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'",)
CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'",)
CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'",)
```

The problem is that when I add CSP protection, Django-Smart-Selects stops working.
I tried to analyze the operation and characteristics of the Plant combobox but apparently nothing changes with or without CSP.

Could someone give me some advice.

It's probably something trivial but I can't understand given my inexperience.
I tried searching on the internet, but it seems that no one until now has come across this problem.

Sorry for the bad English.

Many thanks to all.

Comment: Open dev tools and see the errors when you load the page. They might tell you how you need to modify the various directives of your CSP. If it doesn't make sense or work, you can include the error messages here.

Comment: Thanks @Halvor Sakshaug, your advice helped me to arrive at the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, calmly analyzing the errors present in the console of my website page, I managed to find the solution.
Basically, for some reason that I couldn't fully understand, the CSP protection conflicted with the scripts that made Django-Smart-Selects work.
So here are the changes to the Settings.py worksheet I made that now make Django-Smart-Selects work correctly:

```
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js",
                            "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js",
                            "“https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=[...]",)
```

Thank you all anyway for your patience and availability.